# How to multiply the value of an input textbox?

Tags: actionscript, textbox

In action script I want to multiply an input textbox(x) by some value and then show the answer in a dynamic textbox(y).

When I write this code for a button:

```
on (release) {
    y=Number(x) * 8.0;
}
```

the output is `Nan`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get and set values from a text box using the `text` property of the text box. So your code should be:

```
y.text=Number(x.text) * 8.0;
```

Hope this helps and solves your problem.